# I can’t able to create Event of Office365 using iOS Device but its work in Simulaor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, office365, office365api

I am using **Office365** to create event from my iOS Application. My problem is that I can insert an event from simulator but can’t able to insert event from  iOS device.below is my code.

**Code : -**

```
MSOutlookEvent *eventToCreate = [snippetLibrary outlookEventWithProperties:@[toEmailAddress]
                                                                           subject:subject
                                                                              body:body
                                                                             start:start
                                                                               end: end
                                       ];
    [snippetLibrary createCalendarEvent:eventToCreate
                         completion:^(MSOutlookEvent *addedEvent,  NSError *error) {}
```

**Getting Error:-**

```
Error Domain=Error in the Request Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Error in the Request error 400.)" UserInfo=0x1767db60 {error={
    code = RequestBodyRead;
    message = "Cannot convert the literal '0' to the expected type 'Edm.Boolean'.";
}}
```

Thanks in anticipation !!!

Comment: why downvote plz add a reason.:(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using below changes:

**Step 1:- Office365 SDK -> select OData Folder -> select Property.m file**

**Step 2: Replace Code in Property.m file**

```
-(bool)isBoolean{
    return [self.Type isEqualToString:@"Tc"] || [self.Type isEqualToString:@"TB"];
}
```